# Lock-Up with Gesture Input

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, touch, xamarin, monogame

I'm using MonoTouch in Xamarin Studio to read gestures in my MonoGame. I've added the following section of code to read gestures.

```
while(TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
{
    GestureSample sample = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
}
```

The following was added at the start of the program:

```
        TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.Tap |
                                     GestureType.Hold |
                                     GestureType.None;
```

But when I touch the screen on the simulator or on the device, it completely locks up and becomes non-responsiveness to debugging.

What could cause this lock-up? Have I missed something in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop above will run forever. It needs to be an `if`-statement.

I'm assuming this is MonoGame you're using, but `IsGestureAvailable` will always return the same value within an `Update()` cycle of your `Game` class.

Comment: I amended my code to your suggestion. That makes sense, but made no difference to the lockup.  I have noticed that if I set the build from Universal to iPhone/iPod setting in the properties it no longer locks up. This option did work in previous versions.